# How do I make a selected Combobox value display different text?

Tags: java, combobox, textfield

I am new to Java and couldn't find any answers for my problem that I was able to understand.
I want to make a selected value in my ComboBox change what text is displayed in the textfield.

For example, if the user selects an artist in the combobox, then the artists' albums are displayed in the textfield.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
 String a = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();  
int artists = 0;
switch (artists){
    case 0: jTextField1.setText("Take Care, Nothing Was The Same, Views, More Life, Scorpion");
break;
    case 1: jTextField1.setText("Stoney, Beerbongs & Bentleys");
break;
    case 2: jTextField1.setText("One Love, Listen, Nothing But the Beat");
break;
    case 3: jTextField1.setText("Ready for the Weekend, 18 Months, Motion");
break;
    case 4: jTextField1.setText("Cole World: The Sideline Story, 2014 Forest Hills Drive, 4 Your Eyez Only");
break;
    case 5: jTextField1.setText("My Beautiful Dark Twisted Fantasy, Yeezus, The Life of Pablo, ye");
break;
    case 6: jTextField1.setText("Parachutes, a Rush of Blood to the Head, X&Y, Viva La Vida, Mylo Xyloto");
}
    }
```

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? JavaFX, Swing, AWT, something else?

Comment: @eera-l I think `jCombobox` says enough

Comment: @MarkJeronimus at first he posted the question with no code that's why the question was asked, i even mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch() for your combobox. I've written a code which has the name defined to combobox as cb1. The getSelectedItem() method is used for cb1. You can define the corresponding command for each case (starting from index 0).

```
String a = (String)cb1.getSelectedItem();  
int i = 0;
switch (i){
    case 0: 
break;
}
```

Make sure to end each case with break; or your code will execute repeatedly.
Now if the textfield you're using is t1 then the following code is generalised,

```
switch (i) {
case 0: t1.setText(<whatever you want to display>);
break;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Here's the revisited code:

```
String a = (String)cb1.getSelectedItem();
int i = 0;
switch(i){
    case 0: t1.setText("Take Care, Nothing Was The Same, Views, More Life, Scorpion");
    // for combobox option Drake index = 0
    break;
    case 1: t1.setText("Stoney, Beerbongs & Bentleys");
   // for combobox option post_malone index = 1
    break;
    case 2: t1.setText("One Love, Listen, Nothing But the Beat");
    // for combobox option david_guetta
    break;
 }
```

`switch` is a selection statement that successively tests the value of an expression against alist of integers or characters constants. When a match is found, the statements associated with that constant are executed. Here, the variable i is the expression(the option you choose from combobox) which is evaluated.

Hope this helps again!

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried your code and it displayed values in the textfield, but for some reason the highest case number was always displayed, regardless of the combobox option.

I attached my code to my original question. Hopefully you'll have a solution :)

Comment: Hey, I think you misread something. You don't need to define different variable for every other combobox option. Now, I attached  code on my answer based on the data you used in your code. Check that out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help so far! I removed my previous mistakes, but now it's only displaying the first case (drakes albums). Could you take a look at it please? It's in my question again. Thanks!

Comment: @Downsy of course it's only going to display the first case only, because you set ```artists``` equal to 0 and you never change it, so the ```switch``` will only(and always) catch the case where ```artists=0```,this is not how you retrieve the value of the JComboBox, you should add an ```action listener``` to your JComboBox, I've already provided an example in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57672269/11367165) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangeTextViaCheckbox extends JFrame {


    public ChangeTextViaCheckbox() {
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox("Checkbox 1");
        JCheckBox cb2 = new JCheckBox("Checkbox 2");
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();

        cb1.addActionListener(e -> tf.setText("CB 1 is active"));
        cb2.addActionListener(e -> tf.setText("CB 2 is active"));

        add(cb1);
        add(cb2);
        add(tf);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChangeTextViaCheckbox frame = new ChangeTextViaCheckbox();
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

The both `ActionListener` listen on a performed action. If thats the case, they set a new Text in the `JTextField`.

But it would be better, if you implement it via `JRadioButton` and a `ButtonGroup`. With this there can't be a multiple choice.

Comment: @Downsy I can't comment on the other answer because of not enough reputation. Do you have in every case a break? Can you show us your actual code?

Comment: Added it to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking details and examples, you should post the important parts of your code that you've already written, for example I have no idea now what [GUI] API are you using(for example `swing` or `AWT`), so I strongly advise you to edit your question and provide more details, but either way I'm going to give you a simple example.

I'm going to assume your using the `swing` api, but it shouldn't be that different if your using another GUI api (like `AWT`).

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class SwingExample extends JFrame{  

   public SwingExample(){
      String[] artists = {"artist1","artist2","artist3"};
      Map<String,String> albumOfArtists = new HashMap<String,String>();
      albumOfArtists.put("artist1","album1");
      albumOfArtists.put("artist2","album2");
      albumOfArtists.put("artist3","album3");

      JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox<String>(artists);
      JTextField field1 = new JTextField();

      //You implement an action listener to define what should be done when 
      //an user performs certain operation. An action event occurs, 
      //whenever an action is performed by the user. Examples: When the user 
      //clicks a button, chooses a menu item, presses Enter in a text field.

      //add action listener to your combobox:
      combo1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                  String selectedString=(String)combo1.getSelectedItem(); 
                  field1.setText(albumOfArtists.get(selectedString));
                  //for example if you select artist1 then the text displayed in the text field is: album1
            }
      }

      add(combo1);
      add(field1);

   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {

     JFrame frame = new CreateNewJTextField();
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        createAndShowGUI();
   }
}
```